# How do I add tabs to my facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I realize there is already a similar question, but there aren't any good answers.
I looked all around the facebook developer app, and there isn't an automated way to do this.
Please help!

Comment: To the app itself or its profile page?

Comment: To the app itself. I've seen it done with other apps.

Comment: You just write markup that renders tabs.

Comment: Yes, that is quite documented in this part of the developer section http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/tab-item/  So, I would assume I can just copy and paste the example code into the HTML of my canvas page. But it doesn't even show up.

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this is simple, and smacking me right in the face, but I can't see it...

Answer (score 1):

If your app is an iframe app, fbml will NOT be parsed by facebook. So you can't use fbml in an iframe app. The only thing you can use in iframe apps is the XFMBL or serverfbml version which only supports a little subset of the fbml tags.

See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml/) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) for more details on xfbml and which tags are supported (fb:tabs is NOT)

So I would rather use [jquery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) or something similar and customize it to have the facebook look'n'feel if I wanted tabs in my application :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you cannot use the legacy FBML anymore for new apps.  At least that is what I am told.

You might check [this developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs) and see if the rabbit hole opens up any more for you.

Comment: Yah, I already looked at that page. I did discover something new on the next page after, but it wasn't what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!