# Facebook API FB tags not being parsed

Tags: facebook

I am new to facebook API and I am trying to put some facebook styled tabs on the page, but it fails to display corectly and I am not sure why.
The problem page can be seen here;
http://merseysideregatta.com/app/

Thanks for any help.

John

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put your

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
```

at the end of the body, not in the header. If you want to render FBML after the page has loaded and/or Facebook has been initialized, then use

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

That will scan the page again for FBML and render it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Brent Baisley is right BUT it will parse XFBML which is a subset of FBML (not including the tabs).

See the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575641/how-do-i-add-tabs-to-my-facebook-app/5763733#5763733)

See the [tags parsed by FB.XFBML.parse();](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)